# How can i get rid my Python Flask Pdfkit error 500?

Tags: python, flask, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit, http-status-code-500

I've tried create pdf in new computer. In old computer, everything is fine. ut in new computer, there is error 500 (internal server error).

Here is my code:

```
def print_bobbin_barcode():
    master = Bobbin.query.filter_by(id=request.args.get('i', None, type=int)).first()

    code128 = barcode.get_barcode_class('code128')
    temp = code128(master.barcode, writer=ImageWriter())
    res = temp.save(r'D://Villiger//viliger//static//images//barcode//bobbin//' + str(master.barcode),
                options={"write_text": True, "text_distance": 1.0, "font_size": 13, "module_width": 0.35, "module_height": 13})

    rendered = render_template('bobbin_barcode_pdf.html', rev_doc=master.no_bukti, bobbin_no=master.no_bobbin, barcode=master.barcode)
    options = {'page-width': '50mm', 'page-height': '20mm', 'orientation': 'Portrait',
           'margin-top': '0.1mm', 'margin-bottom': '0.1mm', 'margin-left': '0.1mm', 'margin-right': '0.1mm'}
    pdf = pdfkit.from_string(rendered, False, options=options)

    response = make_response(pdf)
    response.headers["Content-Type"] = 'application/pdf'
    response.headers["Content-Disposition"] = 'inline; filename=Bobbintag Barcode - ' + str(master.no_bobbin) + '.pdf'

    return rendered
```

FYI, pdfkit & wkhtml2pdf alreadey installed. I am already set the path too.
What am i missing?

Comment: can you share the entire traceback